# Data extraction from a generated <script> and process the results

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

[image]

```
 string Url= "https://www.audiusa.com/dealers-webapp/map/dealer/423E99";   
     HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
                            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                            HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url);
     var scriptGoogleTagManager = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//script").Where(x => x.InnerHtml.Contains("window.Audi.Vars.searchType"));
                            if (scriptGoogleTagManager )
                            {
                                foreach(var tag in scriptGoogleTagManager)
                                {
                                    var s = tag.InnerText;
                                    Regex r = new Regex("\\s+window\\.Audi\\.Vars\\.searchResult\\s+\\=\\s+");
                                    Match m = r.Match(s.ToLower());
                                }
                            }
```

In above script I want to extract values after window.Audi.Vars.searchResult =   and window.Audi.Vars.dealers =  .I am facing problem in regex as I dont have much knowledge of it .Kindly help me

Comment: What is the contents of the `s` variable?

Comment: if you will open the page source of Url provided and search the script with the particular string given above .Then you will be able to find the valu of s. @GvS

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to get rid of e.g. 
window.Audi.Vars.searchResult =

```
var extract = s.slice(31); // since the string "window.Audi.Vars.searchResult =" has 31 chars
```

The slice() method extracts parts of a string and returns the extracted parts in a new string. Use the start and end parameters to specify the part of the string you want to extract. Here we only give the start param and it extracts to the end. The first character has the position 0, the second has position 1, and so on. >br> Regex is imho good when relacing, removing chars in a string here a simpler method works.

Modify your code and post the console result:

```
 var scriptGoogleTagManager = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//script").Where(x => x.InnerHtml.Contains("window.Audi.Vars.searchType"));
                    if (scriptGoogleTagManager )
                    {
                        foreach(var tag in scriptGoogleTagManager)
                        {
                            var s = tag.InnerText;
                            console.debug("[content of s] " + s); 
                            var extract = s.slice(31); // since the string
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: slice is showing error that string does not contain its definition @Codebreker007

Comment: please edit your question and insert the result of  the line     console.debug("[content of s] "+ s); placed after var s = tag.InnerText; in your code

Comment: Please see above Image for content of var s @Codebreaker007

Comment: I am interested what does consol.debug give you back. Because on that content we have to do all following operations i'll be back in 3h

Comment: I need the output of the console window to help you not some code you think is the content of var s  - we need to know what is in var s during program execution to debug and adapt your program

Comment: Wait a moment @Codebreaker007

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210170/discussion-between-jiga-and-codebreaker007).